# Conjugate gradient method for an eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume we want to solve the problem $Ax = b$ for a given $A\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let us assume that $b$ is an eigenvector of $A$, i.e. $Ab = \lambda b$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. How can I intuitively see that the conjugate gradient method needs only one iteration step to find the exact solution? Does it have to do with the invariance of the Krylov subspace $\mathcal{K}_m(A,b)$? I have already seen this by explicit computation using the algorithm, yielding $x_1 = \frac{1}{\lambda}b$ in the first iteration step. Therefore, we have $Ax_1 = b$ and the exact solution is found after one iteration step.

Comment: $\mathcal{K}_m(A,b)$ is one-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

I have found (at least) a theoretical result to see why this is true: In fact, one can show that if $b$ is a linear combination of $k$ eigenvectors of $A$, the conjugate gradient method terminates after $k$ steps and yields the exact solution. In this case, we have $k=1$.